# Unable to obtain desired scrolling with ListView.builder - flutter

Tags: android, listview, dart, flutter

I'm trying to achieve a scrolling page that contains a chart and a list of four items such that the whole page must scroll and not partial scrolling of a widget. I created a scrolling list using ListView.builder and wrapped it inside Expanded as a child of Column.
Following is the code:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Container(
            width: 490.0,
            height: 340.0,
            child: new LineChart(),
          ),
          new Expanded(
             //height: 500.0,
            child: new ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (_, int index) {
                return new Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    //displays list details
                    Contents(this.details[index]),
                  ],
                );
              },
              itemCount: this.details.length,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

[The output for the above snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndRNf.gif)

Thus, in order to achieve complete scrolling I included my class(created to display list details) in the ListView.builder itself. After running the program, I obtained the full page scrolling but a separate chart was created for each of the items in the ListView. I realised that the 'itemCount'  was applied to both the widgets.
Following is the code:

```
@override
Widget createListView(BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
  return new ListView.builder(
    itemCount: this.details.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Container(
            width: 490.0,
            height: 340.0,
            child: LineChart(),
          ),
          //displays list details
          Contents(this.details[index]),
          new Divider(height: 2.0,),
        ],
      );
    },
  );
}
```

[The output for the above snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndRNf.gif)

P.S.: AsyncSnapshot snapshot has nothing to do with the current page displayed.

Can someone please tell me about the mistake that I made in the above snippets? If the error is big or complicated, then please could you provide the necessary code?

Answer (score 2):

To stop scrolling of your inner lists you can use physics: `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` in your inner list view. This way their individual scrollability will be removed and they will act like they are a part of your outer list view

Comment: I will try what you've suggested, although I obtained results using Slivers